# 'Cannot redefine property: __internal__deprecationWarning' in a Shopify Hydrogen project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, shopify-hydrogen

I'm buildling a Shopify Hydrogen project with Remix and Typescript and all of a sudden I keep encountering the following error when I run `npm run dev`.  It was working fine 5 hours prior, come back from dinner and now app does not launch.

```
╭─ error ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                               │
│  Cannot redefine property: __internal__deprecationWarning                     │
│                                                                               │
│  To investigate the issue, examine this stack trace:                          │
│    at defineProperty                                                          │
│    at <anonymous> (@babel/types/lib/index.js:66)                              │
│      Object.defineProperty(exports, "__internal__deprecationWarning", {       │
│    at _compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241)                        │
│    at js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295)                              │
│    at load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091)                            │
│    at _load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938)                            │
│    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115)                         │
│    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130)                             │
│    at <anonymous> (@babel/types/src/builders/validateNode.ts:3)               │
│      import { BUILDER_KEYS } from "../index.ts";                              │
│    at _compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241)                        │
│                                                                               │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __internal__deprecationWarning
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projectFolder projectFolder/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/index.js:66:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projectFolder folder/jmlshopifystore/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/validateNode.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
```

- Reverted to an several earlier commits — no luck. Doesn't seem to matter which branch or commit.
- Added babel/core and babel/types as dev dependencies in order to get latest versions of possible packages.
- Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled every step of the way; even cleared cache.
- Tried updating all dependencies one by one with node_modules and package-lock.json reinstalls; no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I went from Node v20.6.0 down to v20.5.1 and it worked again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using NVM and use an older version than the current one

In my case as of today, it was version 20.6 downgraded to version 20.5
steps:

1. Install and setup NVM
2. Check current version
3. downgrade by installing the downgraded version using  `nvm install 20.5`
4. Enable the later version `nvm use 20.5`

Although I am using NUXT I think it will help in your case too

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I had the same issue with a Nuxt project and downgrading to 20.5 fixed it for now.